# Problem in Angular 8 iterating non-empty array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, frontend, angular8

I'm having a rather strange problem fetching an array using http requests in Angular 8.
The request looks like this:

```
getPort(): any {    
return this.http.get(this.portsApiUrl).toPromise().then(data => {
    let masterSchedule = data["masterSchedule"];         
          for (const d of masterSchedule as any) {        
            this.portList.push(d);        
          } 
});
```

This code works fine, and it retrieves the list of ports in a timely manner; I then pass it to another component using @Input. The list gets to the component fine; if I log it through the console on the OnInit method of said component, the list is shown correctly.

The problem occurs when I try to iterate over the list using ngFor. Trying to pass the html the {{item.departurePort}} (which is the correct variable name, since I can see the objects in the array and their respective variables' names) will end up throwing an *undefined* error.
Calling portList.length within the component at any time, however, will show the correct number of elements within the array. 
It is very strange, to be honest. Here's the console log of the list being printed in the onInit method:

[image]

And here's the error:

[image]

Just in case, here's the html code that iterates over the array:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
<ul class="flags">
  <li ngFor="let item of portList">          
    <p><a style="color: #656D78;">{{item.departurePort}}</a>
        </p>            
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First thing I notice is that you don't have an asterisk before the ngFor. But in case that's a typo, can you acces any other properties from the item iterator?

Comment: One quick fix could be to use the `?.` (optional chaining operator): `{{item`?.departurePort}}`. Though you are pushing null values to your array so you should fix the problem at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see what `item` has properties by using `json` pipe:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of portList">          
    <p>
        <a style="color: #656D78;">{{item | json}}</a>
    </p>            
</li>
```

Based on this you can write desired property. In addition, you can use `?.` operator to prevent errors:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of portList">          
    <p>
        <a style="color: #656D78;">{{item?.yourPropertyName }}</a>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template you should use "?" :

```
<li *ngFor="let item of portList">          
    <p><a style="color: #656D78;">{{item?.departurePort}}</a>
        </p>            
 </li>
```

also you may want to use Observables instead of promise, it's way more powerful.